# Cloned app from heroku and now I get a error Unknown Attribute

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku, migrate

Last week my Ubuntu crashed. I did have my app on heroku.

So I reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 and cloned the heroku app.

After that I migrated the database, ect.

But when I start the server I get a Unknown Attribute error..

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in SurveysController#new
unknown attribute: survey_id
```

Does someone knows a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by dropping the PG database and running

> rake db:create

and

> rake db:migrate

again.

I dont know exactly why it worked. But its working now. Maybe there went something wrong with creating the PG database in the first time.